# List<Object> get elements by index and direct access to an object

Tags: java, list, groovy, listobject

I have a problem with accessing an object directly. I have a list of objects which looks like that:  `[{companyId=2024, companyName=City Net}, {companyId=2025, companyName=McDrive}]` when I try to retrieve an element at 0 index `{companyId=2024, companyName=City Net}` and after that I can't retrieve for example `companyId`. I have tried to get an access with this solution:

```
var getDataItems =  path.getList("data.items");
getDataItems.get(0).companyId
```

but java did not recognizes `companyId` after the `.`, but in groovy I can have direct access. Why in java I can't access an object like this way?

Comment: What is the Java class of the list elements? Please show us the source code of this class.

Comment: getDataItems is class java.util.ArrayList and getDataItems.get(index) is class java.util.LinkedHashMap

Comment: So ... if the element type is a `Map`, you need to use `get(o).get("companyId")`.

Comment: In java you could use `map.get("companyId")` to access map element by key.

Comment: getDataItems.get(0).get("Id");  when I use this I am receiving an error: Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Object' - get("Id")

Comment: You should read about Java Generics. In your case, the list should be declared as `List<Map<String,Object>>`. Then Java knows that the elements, being of type `Map<String,Object>`, have a `get()` method, and that method returns an unspecific Object.